# How to use SCNNode's look(at:up:localFront:)

Tags: swift, scenekit

What does the variable **localFront** refer to in the function **look(at:up:localFront:)**?

I am trying to get my SCNCamera to look at an SCNNode. I understand what **at** and **up** refer to, but cannot find any information about **localFront**.

Comment: Did you watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/604/ ?

Comment: No, I have not watched it. Does it contain the answer that I seek?

Comment: So you want _me_ to watch it _for_ you?

Comment: Sure, if you want to.

Comment: Considering the horrible English of the speaker I wish I had someone watched it for me.

Comment: I watched the movie, but did not find any mention of localFront...

Answer (score 3):

It refers to where you want the eyes to be of the object you make look at something, which is normally the localFront property of the node you are looking with (i,e. the camera node). In case where you use it for other nodes than the camera, it can be used to make an object point towars another object with another “side” than its front. For example, you could have a car that you want its side to look at (line up with) the side of another car. Or you could have an evil monster with eyes in front an in the back of its head so it can look at something from both sides :)